# Given three *slightly* different copies of a class object, how can I efficiently store the difference between them?

Tags: c++, class

**Direct Question**: With three (or more) nearly identical copies of a class object, how can I best (or most efficiently) store the differences between them?

**Background:** I have an algorithm which requires a set of parameters:

```
struct params
{
   std::string A;
   std::string B;

   double C;
   double D;

   userDefinedTypeDef S;
};
```

And I want to call my algorithm three times.  The first time, C = 3 & S = 'foo'.  The second time, C = 4 & S = 'foo'.  And the third time, C = 4 & S = 'bar'.
Now the example given is merely for illustration, the true object is a class, not a structure, and has a few hundred members. I also want to call the algorithm many more than three times, so I don't want to have extra copies of this object running around.  So what is the best pattern / implementation / method for storing only the difference between two class objects?

In other words, how can I store "Object 2 is the same as &(Object 1) except that C = 4"??

**Edit**: As noted in the comments below, I'd really like to avoid altering the function call as well as arrays of either the parameter class object or the member objects.  My purpose in doing so is to keep one copy, ala "currentParam" and then keep a list of the differences between successive calls.  That way, I can simply update the values which changed, leaving all else fixed, and use the function given to me.

That said, what's the easiest way to do this?  Create a class with boolean flags 'member1_changed'? And then use a union?  I'm fairly stuck -- been puzzling a bit about sparse matrix storage and how that might be related -- hence why I asked the question.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400) may also be related.

Comment: What do you know about these objects?  Will you read successive full objects from some input and calculate deltas, or will you read the deltas directly?  If you only want to have one full object in memory, and you want to preserve the ordering, then each delta will have to be from the previous object.  You might reasonably encode each delta as a containers of (field ids + boost::any or variant or home-spun-union), and provide a corresponding update function in your class.

Comment: I'd like to create the deltas directly instead of creating the full objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the [Flyweight design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to be of interest.  It is designed specifically to solve your problem.

Here's one way to store the differences:

Step 1: Replace all your members with pointers to the members.  Yes, this adds a little memory overhead.

Step 2: Have classes store shallow copies of shared members instead of deep copies.

If your classes are not immutable, this technique becomes more complicated, though the basic idea is still doable.

Note that this does reduce memory footprint, but will also reduce spatial locality of memory references.  This may slow down your program significantly.  It also adds an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: +1, although the discussed proposal is somewhat different from the pattern itself.

Answer (score 1):

A few hundred members?  That sounds like bad design right from the get-go to me.  I can't even think of an object I could describe that requires so many things.  I can think of a system which does.  But to be fair, I'm not criticizing you as I don't even know if you originally wrote this.  I'd look at ways in which I could intelligently split the class into subclasses or even group the data into better representations.  That's a first start.

After that I'd also look at perhaps rewriting your function so that it accepts just the parameters it's operating on:

```
void foo(Bar _objectWithTonsOfMembers){ //stuff...
```

into

```
void foo(int itemCount, double price, double discount, Customer customer){ //stuff
```

Once you have that done you can think about handling requests with different parameters.  [Boost::Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html) combined with [Boost::Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function.html) helps when dealing exactly with these types of situations:

```
boost::function<void(int,double)> refinedFoo = boost::bind(foo, _1, _2, 4.09, Customer("Pam"));
refinedFoo(1, 3.0);
refinedFoo(2, 2.0);
```

Now I can easily call the function I want only with the parameters which are changing.

**Edit**:

To clarify what I meant my "subclasses," I was not referring to inheritance but rather structure.  Hence, I want you to take some class "Foo" and make it into a composition of classes Bar, Baz, Biff, and Bam.  These should be broken down into logical elements as they are used within your code.

And by that I mean, if you have a function which operates only of 4 member variables and those members variables are in general always operated on in the same manner then that is a good place to create a new class or struct.

Comment: I may have oversimplified things a bit.  Yes, the object which I don't want to make copies of actually has eight subclasses (A, A2, B, B2, C, D, E, F) where A2 is derived from A, B2 is derived from B, etc.  The algorithm is a statistical sampler and it actually needs only one or two of the subclasses each of which can differ between subsequent calls.  I have essentially no flexibility in altering the function, but likewise I'd prefer not to convert all of the sub-class members to arrays.

Comment: @M. Tibbits when I said subclasses I didn't mean inheritance, though that's hard to distinguish from my response.  I meant split A into several different classes so that A is a composition of those classes.  Let me edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: I believe I understood what you meant, but let me provide a touch more information -- in my parameter object (A, A2, B, B2, C, D, E, F), F is only a typedef 'algType' and based on the algorithm type, the function Sample(param) calls a different sampler which needs one of the subclasses: A, A2, B, B2, C, D, or E.  Between successive class a member of A might be different, F might change, or perhaps all of B changes -- But my point in asking the question the way I did is b/c I can't change the function definition and I don't want to change the composition to hold arrays of A, A2, etc.

Comment: I could change the subclasses to hold arrays A2.member1[call1] and use an index for each call, but  I'm really hesitant to do so because almost all of the subclass members could change between function calls and I wanted to avoid arrays.